# Is it possible to use PyPy with PyGame?

Tags: python, pygame, pypy

I've been searching and have seen mixed things on the internet about whether it is possible to use PyGame with PyPy. Particularly there is this project https://bitbucket.org/stefanor/pygame-pypy, although I'm really struggling to build it on Windows. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays, you should look here: http://morepypy.blogspot.ch/2013/12/pygame-cffi.html.  Although this pygame-cffi might be incomplete, if you're just missing a couple of functions, adding them should be rather easy (then contribute them back!).